# Bash: How insert text with special character in sqlite3?

Tags: bash, sqlite

Let's imagine I want to save the text of various **bash script** in my database with sqlite3.

If my script do this

```
VARIABLE=$(cat "bashScript.sh")
sqlite3 mydb.db "CREATE TABLE data (myBash BLOB)" 
sqlite3 mydb.db "INSERT INTO data VALUES (${VARIABLE})"
```

Because the bash script will have all the special character, this will not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the value in the Insert statement, and you'll want to protect quotes in the value itself: untested:

```
sql_value=$(sed 's/'\''/&&/g' <<< "$VARIABLE")
sqlite3 mydb.db "insert into data values ('$sql_value')"
```

Comment: Good idea, use `''` inside a `""`, so the `$sql_value` work. The unique character I have to worry is the `'`? What you do is replace all `'` by `&&`? And what the `<<<` really do? I search and don't find the mean of 3 `<`

Comment: In the right-hand side of sed's `s///` command, a `&` means "use whatever was matched on the left-hand side" -- so I'm replacing each single quote with 2 single quotes. The `<<<` is a [bash here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)